# VSCode: Jupyter won't export as Python script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying not to get too frustrated with VSCode and the scattered subfolders it's been creating, but I'm tearing my hair out over this one:

The instructions for exporting from a Jupyter notebook within VSCode are simple -- hit "Export As," then select "Python script." The error I get is: "Export failed. Please check the 'Python' output panel for further details."

The output panel includes this:

```
    raise ValueError('No template sub-directory with name %r found in the following paths:\n\t%s' % (base_template, paths))
ValueError: No template sub-directory with name 'python' found in the following paths:
    C:\Users\dures\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
    c:\program files (x86)\python\share\jupyter
    C:\ProgramData\jupyter
```

I've created the relevant sub-directories, but I have no idea how to create a "template sub-directory."

More generally, is there a better way to make sure everything I want to use in VSCode is in the same place and on PATH?

Comment: Since the Jupyter notebook function in VSCode is provided by Python extensions, it is recommended that you try to use the latest version of Python extensions or use other versions of Python extensions and reload VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

Check and confirm you're using Python 3.7 and above. See the image to below

You're likely running Python 3 or a lesser version not supported.

[image: Where to see the python version running]

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions at: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex

On windows try:

```
pip install nbconvert
pip install pandoc
```

Then install LateX project at: https://www.latex-project.org/get/

For Linux I did this and it worked:

```
pip install nbconvert
sudo apt-get install pandoc
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-plain-generic
```

Restart vscode and try again

Answer (score 0):

Install these libraries, then try again:

```
%pip install nbconvert
%pip install pandoc
%pip install pyppeteer
```